# IAPHelper Fail Cannot connect to iTunes Store

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

I hope someone can help me. I have been working on this issues for over a week, and I know when I am beat and have to ask for assistance. I have an app that I am add Auto-Renewable In App Purchases to. I am using IAPHelper which can be found on GitHub. I can make the purchase and that part works, but I keep getting the error Cannot Connect to iTunes Store, and error code is 0. I have used other sample demos and I get the same result: Can make purchase, but cannot verify it by connecting to iTunes Store.

Here is what I can confirm:

1. Yes, I am connecting to iTunes Sandbox
2. Yes, I have tried this on both the Xcode simulator and an external iPad with the same results.
3. Yes, I have used multiple testing user accounts.
4. Yes, All IDs are correct in both Xcode and iTunes Connect - they match.
5. And tons of other testing and hacking to try to get this to work.

Has anyone else had this issue and been able to solve it?

You can see the source code by Googling for IAPHelper on GitHub, or copy and paste this link: https://github.com/saturngod/IAPHelper

Comment: Have You tried it on device?

Comment: Pleas show your code and where you are getting the error

Comment: You can see all the code as I said above by going to the link on GitHub - IAPHelper. The only difference is that I added my ShareSecert and IAPIDs. How do I post code here? I don't see the option anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this myself. For anyone that might come across the same problem here is how I solved it. I took an iPad and reset all the info and data starting it as a NEW iPad. I used the test account Apple ID to setup the iPad. When I ran the app again using this iPad for testing it all worked. I would say that Apple still has issues with the Xcode simulator. I worked for over two weeks trying to get the Simulator to work, but with no luck. So I would suggest that you use an actual device for all your testing, and make sure you reset it between changing test accounts. Good Luck!